# Issue with ParameterizedTypeReference with WebClient. Expected List<?>; found capture<?>

Tags: java, spring, webclient

I am using RestTemplate and am now refactoring to using WebClient. Now, I am writing a wrapper around WebClient and am facing this issue. First let me show you how I have the wrapper written around resttemplate.

```
/**
* Build the local map of HttpClientParamRefType as key to the ParameterizedTypeReference as value
*/
private final static Map<HttpClientParamRefType,ParameterizedTypeReference> paramTypeRefMap = new HashMap<>() ;
static {
  paramTypeRefMap.put(HttpClientParamRefType.DATA_RESOURCE, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DataResource>>(){} );
  paramTypeRefMap.put(HttpClientParamRefType.GENERIC, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>(){} );
}

.
.
.

public ResponseEntity doGet (uri, HttpClientParamRefType type){
  try{
    return restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, paramTypeRefMap.get(httpClientParamRefType) );
  }catch(HttpServerErrorException e){
    // Handling errors
  }
}
```

The above piece of code works fine. I am trying to do the same thing with WebClient. I am not able to pass the ParameterizedTypeReference from the map to bodyToMono(). It works only if I pass it directly.

```
public List<DataResource> getLens(HttpClientParamRefType httpClientParamRefType){

  // dlClient is initialized, nothing too special; just setting json
  return this.dlClient.get()
          .uri(datalensControlplaneUrl + "/resource?resourceType=" + SchemaType.DRUID.getName())
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(paramTypeRefMap.get(httpClientParamRefType))
//        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DataResource>>(){})  // <----- This works!
          .block();

}
```

Any idea how to make it work? The exact error I get is this -

```
Error:(54, 23) java: incompatible types: capture#1 of ? cannot be converted to java.util.List<x.x.x.x.x.DataResource>
```

Comment: Your map has an incorrect / insufficient generic bound for the Value type, it is just `ParameterizedTypeReference`, not `ParameterizedTypeReference<Something>` - it is certainly not `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DataResource>>`.

Comment: Of course it does not work? You explicitly return List<DataLensResource> but whats stopping you from giving HttpClientParaRefType as GENERIC? Then the return type is String which directly collides with method definition.

Comment: @luk2302 - Defining map this way doesn't seem to help. Thoughts?

`private final static Map<HttpClientParamRefType,ParameterizedTypeReference<?>> paramTypeRefMap = new HashMap<>() ;`

@Worthless - Sorry, fixed the question.. I was removing by actual object names but oops, missed one. Sure, I can get the JSON response in string and then serialize it later from my caller. But I am trying to understand how to make this work.